# Why don't Julia closures copy arrays?

Tags: julia

Just discovered a nasty bug in my program based on the fact that Julia does not copy arrays when defining a closure. This makes continuation programming hard. What was the motivation for this design choice?

Any suggestions for decoupling the state of my closure from the program state?

As an example

```
l = [2 1; 0 0];
f = x -> l[2,2];
```

Then f(1) = 0 but if you change l[2,2] = 1, then f(1) = 1.

Comment: `const l2 = copy(l); f = x -> l2[2,2]`?

Comment: I'm curious — what language are you coming from that you'd expect such behavior?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard `deepcopy` instead of `copy` in some cases (for example array of arrays).

Comment: true --15 chars

Comment: But Tasos' answer is the right approach.

Comment: @MattB. I'm a mathematician and used to functional languages. I also use matlab; good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption that this is a "closure" does not hold. `l` is not a "closed" variable in the context of the anonymous function at that point. It is simply a reference to a variable inherited from 'external' scope (since it has not been redefined locally inside the anonymous function).

Here's an example of a *true* closure:

```
f = let l=[2 1;0 0]
  x -> l[2,2];
end
```

The variable `l` now is local to the `let` block, and not present at global scope. `f` still has access to it, even though it has technically gone out of scope. This is what a closure means.

As a result of `l` having gone out of scope, it is no longer accessible except through `f` which is a closure having access to it as a closed variable.

---

PS. I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that what you're expecting was matlab-like behaviour. The big difference with matlab is that when you define an anonymous function handle there, it captures the current state of the workspace **by copying all the variables** and making them part of the function 'object'. You can confirm this by using the `functions` command. Matlab doesn't have references in the same way as julia. This is a strength of julia, not a weakness, as it allow the user to make use of optimizations that avoid reallocation of memory, that are harder to achieve in matlab*.

<sub>* though in fairness, matlab shines in other ways, by attempting to optimise this for you</sub>

---

**EDIT:** Liso pointed out a very important pitfall in the comments. Assume `l` already exists in the global workspace, and we type

```
let l=l
```

while this is perfectly valid syntax, making `l` a local variable to the `let` block, this is still initialised simply as a *reference* to the global `l`. Therefore any changes to the global `l` will still affect the closure, which is not what you want. In this case, you should be trying to 'mimic' matlab behaviour by making a *copy* (or a deep copy, depending on your use case), such that the local variable is truly independent of anything else once it goes out of scope and becomes 'closed' i.e.

```
let l = deepcopy(l)
```

Also, for completeness, when one makes a closure in julia, it is worth pointing out how this is implemented under the hood: your resulting `f` function is simply a callable object, containing a field for each 'closed' variable it needs to be aware of; you could even access this as `f.l`.

Comment: in case you have l defined yet and want to use `let l=l` then you probably want to **copy whole variable** via `let l=deepcopy(l)`

Comment: Sorry I hope it would not seems too pedantic. But I think it is better to start with proper description to beginner.  In case `let l=l`  local l is not referencing to global l. Local l is copy of global l and both are (different) references to same structure (here array). If we change global l by `l = something` it does not affect local l (and structure to local l is binding). It just cause that global l is binding to other value. But if we do for example `l[1] = something` then we are modifying structure to which both ls (global and local) are bound. It is why we could need (deep)copy here.

Comment: @Liso I appreciate what you're saying, and it's true that variables in julia are generally best thought of as 'labels' to an object in memory, but I feel that trying to explain this would go into too much depth and would confuse more than it would help here. Best to keep it short (I already added more to the answer than I wished) ... thank you for the comment though, hopefully someone interested enough will follow the conversation and decide to find out more about this! :)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou fantastic answer, thank you for your completeness. Indeed, the problem is that I'm a mathematician (I'm thinking of anonymous functions from functional languages) and a Matlab user; you guessed correctly. It makes sense that passing references is faster and is not a weakness. Thanks again to everyone, very helpful.